# How to detect if iOS devices is connected using wifi in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In an old, Objective-C based project I have been using the below code to detect if the iOS devices is currently connected using Wifi (not cellular).

My attempts to translate this code into Swift 5 failed due to the Objective-C pointers. **Is there a clean way to use this solution in Swift?**

Or are are there better ways to solve this nowerdays? I found solutions using the [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) port to Swift or `NWPathMonitor()`. While they seem to work in general, these solution are used to monitor the connection state and send notifications on changes while one time checks are not (well) supported.

Event though these solution could be used to get the **current** connection state, this is done using delegate callback methods or closures. Thus it is not possible to use these solutions in existing code which was created to work "synchronously" (without callbacks/closures).

**Is there a simply way to use `localWiFiAvailable` in Swift?**

**The code:**

```
+ (BOOL)localWiFiAvailable {
    struct ifaddrs *addresses;
    struct ifaddrs *cursor;
    BOOL wiFiAvailable = NO;
    if (getifaddrs(&addresses) != 0) return NO;
    
    cursor = addresses;
    while (cursor != NULL) {
        if ((cursor -> ifa_addr -> sa_family == AF_INET) && !(cursor -> ifa_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK)) { // Ignore the loopback address
            // Check for WiFi adapter
            #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
                wiFiAvailable = true;
                break;
            #else
                if (strcmp(cursor -> ifa_name, "en0") == 0) {
                    wiFiAvailable = YES;
                    break;
                }
            #endif
        }
        cursor = cursor -> ifa_next;
    }
    
    freeifaddrs(addresses);
    return wiFiAvailable;
}
```

**Details on why `NWPathMonitor()` cannot be used:**

As @baronfac pointed out in his comment `NWPathMonitor()` can also deliver the **current** state, but this can only be done using its `.pathUpdateHandler` closure.

I am using a third-party library where I can override a `souldSendData() -> Bool` method. Sending the data should not be allowed on mobile connection but only on WiFi. The methodes requires an instant decision to return true or false. Waiting for the closure is thus not possible.

So, I am limited by the existing class here. Yes, connection could change any second, however this is a different problem. e.g. NWPathMonitor can be used to cancel the transfer when connection changes to mobile.

Solving this problem in Objectiv-C was no problem using the code shown above. The question is simply, if such a "direct" solution is possible in Swift as well. While using the Objectiv-C code in the Swift project would be possible I would prefer to keep the project Swift only.

Comment: NWPathMonitor is the recommended approach. A one time check is fairly pointless.  Networking can change at any time. Just because you are connected to wifi now doesn't mean you will be in half a second. NWPathMonitor can give the state of connectivity "now".  You can simply stop the monitor if you don't want ongoing state changes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Paulw11, the recommended approach is using NWPathMonitor. A common practice is the following within a UIViewController - class:

```
private var monitor: NWPathMonitor? 

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    monitor?.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
        if !path.isExpensive { // this means the device is connected via WiFi
            // enter your code here
        }
    }
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
    monitor?.start(queue: queue)    // start to monitor the connection
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    monitor?.cancel()    // end to monitor the connection 
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to FLichter and Rob Napier for the clarification. Maybe it helps to use this approach:

```
func shouldSendData() -> Bool {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    return !monitor.currentPath.isExpense
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this will not work in my case. I am using a third-party class where I can override a `souldSendData() -> Bool` method to decide whether data should be send right now or not. Sending the data should not be allowed on mobile connection but only on WiFi. The methodes requires an instant decision to return true or false. Waiting for the `monitor?.pathUpdateHandler` closure is thus not possible. Yes, connection could change any second, however this is a different problem. e.g. NWPathMonitor can be used to cancel the transfer when connection changes to mobile...

Comment: "Sending the data should not be allowed on mobile connection but only on WiFi" This is configured in the URLSession using `allowsCellularAccess`. Also, you can just track the results of NWPathMonitor and return the last value you received.

Comment: @RobNapier This is correct of course, but as described I am not working with `URLSession` directly but with a  third party library and I cannot change the internal implementation details. As described in the updated question, the goal is to make an instant decision based on whether the device is currently connected via wifi or not. `URLSession` cannot solve this given problem, can it?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant above by NWPathMonitor only being usable in a callback. There's NWPathMonitor's `currentPath` property for this purpose.

Comment: (Note that your ObjC code is making some assumptions about network interface names that may not always be true. I'd be particularly concerned about personal hotspot connections, which are "wifi" but can actually be cellular, VPN configurations, captured networks, and other uncommon setups. The existence of an en0 does not mean data will go to wifi, or that wifi is appropriate.)